# Is it possible in maven to use other local repository for installing artifacts?

Tags: maven, repository, artifacts

When I run `mvn install`, the compiled artifacts lands in my local repository, the same as this where remote artifacts are installed. Sometimes it is the problem, because you are mixing public jars, which have zero security value (they are already public) with those with highest security value (those you create). Somewhere between goes artifacts downloaded from non-public repos. This remix is hard to manage from security point of view.

The most problematic is the need to give full repository to the new developer (yes, of course, he can run maven and wait the whole day for all plugins etc. to download, but this is the loss of time). It is not easy to remove everything that he should not have access to.

I've tried to find in maven documentation a switch for choosing the location where *install* is made, but this documentation is quite hard to search throug, so the fact I've found nothing doesn't make me believe no such options exists or was not tried to be created. So I'm querying the community for such solution.

Comment: The question is what do you understand under *security* in this relationship?

Comment: I mean that some files should not be accessible to some people. Your private project should not be available for everyone except your partners for example :)

Comment: See my answer about repository manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best recommendation i can give is to use a repository manager like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org) or [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) (alphabetical order). Furthermore it would not make sense to install files into a different location, cause you will need to change for builds between several local repositories which will destroy the idea of the local repository.

Comment: I agree. The repository manager will then cache the bundles that come off the internet, so the next guy that you work with, will get the artifacts from your local network instead of the public internet. It should be really quick.

Comment: Not should ;-) it is quite quick.